# How do I solve make: None: Command not found issue?

Tags: c++, scala, installation, makefile, z3

I am having trouble understanding this error.

```
make: None: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:3879: api/api_commands.o] Error 127
```

I have tried looking but I can't find an answer to the specific issue `make: None:`.
The full issue and error message is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396956/scalaz3-installation-issue) for clarification.

Help on this would be highly appreciated.

#### Update

The `make` file consists of the following (line 3879 separated from the rest for clarification):

```
...

includes_65 = -I../src/tactic/portfolio -I../src/tactic/smtlogics -I../src/ackermannization -I../src/model -I../src/ast/rewriter -I../src/ast -I../src/util -I../src/math/polynomial -I../src/math/automata -I../src/solver -I../src/tactic -I../src/ast/proofs -I../src/sat/sat_solver -I../src/tactic/core -I../src/ast/macros -I../src/ast/normal_forms -I../src/tactic/aig -I../src/tactic/bv -I../src/ast/rewriter/bit_blaster -I../src/tactic/arith -I../src/sat -I../src/sat/tactic -I../src/nlsat/tactic -I../src/nlsat -I../src/smt/tactic -I../src/smt -I../src/cmd_context -I../src/interp -I../src/smt/proto_model -I../src/smt/params -I../src/ast/pattern -I../src/parsers/smt2 -I../src/parsers/util -I../src/ast/substitution -I../src/math/grobner -I../src/math/euclid -I../src/math/simplex -I../src/ast/fpa -I../src/util/lp -I../src/muz/fp -I../src/muz/base -I../src/qe -I../src/muz/pdr -I../src/muz/transforms -I../src/math/hilbert -I../src/muz/dataflow -I../src/muz/clp -I../src/muz/tab -I../src/muz/rel -I../src/muz/bmc -I../src/muz/duality -I../src/duality -I../src/muz/ddnf -I../src/muz/spacer -I../src/tactic/nlsat_smt -I../src/tactic/ufbv -I../src/tactic/fpa -I../src/tactic/sls -I../src/math/subpaving/tactic -I../src/math/subpaving -I../src/math/interval -I../src/math/realclosure -I../src/opt -I../src
api/z3_macros.h.node: ../src/api/z3_macros.h
    @echo done > api/z3_macros.h.node
api/z3_api.h.node: ../src/api/z3_api.h
    @echo done > api/z3_api.h.node
...
api/api_ast_vector$(OBJ_EXT): ../src/api/api_ast_vector.cpp api/z3.h.node api/api_log_macros.h.node api/api_context.h.node api/api_ast_vector.h.node ast/ast_translation.h.node ast/ast_smt2_pp.h.node
    @echo src/api/api_ast_vector.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(includes_65) $(CXX_OUT_FLAG)api/api_ast_vector$(OBJ_EXT) ../src/api/api_ast_vector.cpp
api/api_bv$(OBJ_EXT): ../src/api/api_bv.cpp api/z3.h.node api/api_log_macros.h.node api/api_context.h.node api/api_util.h.node ast/bv_decl_plugin.h.node
    @echo src/api/api_bv.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(includes_65) $(CXX_OUT_FLAG)api/api_bv$(OBJ_EXT) ../src/api/api_bv.cpp
api/z3_replayer.h.node: ../src/api/z3_replayer.h api/z3.h.node util/z3_exception.h.node
    @echo done > api/z3_replayer.h.node
api/api_commands$(OBJ_EXT): ../src/api/api_commands.cpp api/z3.h.node api/z3_replayer.h.node
    @echo src/api/api_commands.cpp

    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(includes_65) $(CXX_OUT_FLAG)api/api_commands$(OBJ_EXT) ../src/api/api_commands.cpp

api/api_config_params$(OBJ_EXT): ../src/api/api_config_params.cpp api/z3.h.node 
...
```

Since the previous lines in the `make` file are of similar format and did not cause any errors, the problem must lie within the `api_commands.cpp` file. I have looked into this file, but I can't understand what is happening in this code exactly, so I cannot interpret where a `None` variable is created.

The `api_commands.cpp` file in question is 4856 lines long, but it consists of several functions of ther format

```cpp
void exec_Z3_params_set_bool(z3_replayer & in) {
  Z3_params_set_bool(
    reinterpret_cast<Z3_context>(in.get_obj(0)),
    reinterpret_cast<Z3_params>(in.get_obj(1)),
    in.get_symbol(2),
    in.get_bool(3));
}
```

and a function `void register_z3_replayer_cmds(z3_replayer & in)` containing lines such as

```cpp
in.register_cmd(16, exec_Z3_params_set_bool, "Z3_params_set_bool");
```

If anyone is familiar with such or similar code and would know how this file is creating a `None` variable, your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to go into the Makefile in the source directory (wherever `sbt` unpacked it) and find which variable expands to `None`. Then `make` tries to execute this as a command.
Look at the line 3879 of that `Makefile`.
For more specific help, you need to ask the maintainers of `python/z3` package.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have updated the post accordingly

Comment: The first thing you should do is remove the `@` prefixes on your recipes, at least the ones that are failing.  Adding these is like adding a blindfold before trying to cook a meal... why would you do that?  If you look at the output make prints instead of hiding it, then your problem will be much simpler to solve.  My suspicion is that in this recipe, for some reason we cannot determine based on this small amount of makefile, the `CXX` variable contains the value `None` instead of the compiler.  If so, you'll have to go find where this variable is defined to figure out why.

Comment: Regarding `@` you might consider reading http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/ for tips on better ways to handle this.